# REST API Batch Processes - 401 Unauthorized (User is not authenticated in expected context)

Tags: rest, batch-processing, intershop

I am trying to list batch processes using the Intershop REST API (https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2500N0):

```
GET http://localhost/INTERSHOP/rest/BOS/inSPIRED-Site/inTRONICS/batchprocesses/productimports
```

I use basic authentication with user 'admin', but still get:
401 Unauthorized (User is not authenticated in expected context)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mentioned REST API call is part of the Intershop Backoffice REST API.
It is configured to work only via HTTPS protocol.
(See app_bo_catalog PrefixREST-Start pipeline).
When used with HTTP protocol an error message is returned.
Try to access the REST call via HTTPS.